# How can I prevent a desk from being bleached by the sun?

Tags: wood

I have a computer desk that's situated close to a window, and over the years the sun has stained the top of the desk, I'm looking for a type of desk/type of wood that won't get stained by the sun? I'd preferably want a wooden desk.

Comment: One not made out of wood?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'd prefer wooden desk.

Answer (score 1):

Coat the desk top with a UV resistant coating like a good marine spar varnish. Won't stop it completely but will slow it down significantly.

If you get a desk top made of a real wood top (not a paper thin veneer over particle board) you can sand and restain in over and over when it fades too much.